# How to start my program, with different settings selected, using a command line parameter?

Tags: c#, winforms, command-line-arguments

In a "settings" tab of my windows forms application i have a checkbox that, if checked, it will disable some features of my program, in order to make it more compatible. By default that checkbox is unchecked (all features enabled).

What i'm trying to achieve is to give the user the option to launch my program through cmd with a "/c" parameter (like: myprogram.exe /c) And that would make my program to launch with that checkbox unchecked (some features disabled)

This way during the load of my main form i could have something like:

```
if (program launched with /c parameter)
{
    checkbox1.checked = false; // or something else 
}
```

Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: If you want the option to be specified through command line args than read in the command line args to determine if the setting should be enabled, rather than using `Settings` if you don't actually want the semantics that `Settings` provides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're looking for

```
Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
```

This will allow you access to your command line args, off of which you can toggle your switches.

If you're using Linq, you could do something like this to get the boolean value you're looking for:

```
var args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
if(args.Any(arg => arg == "/c"))
{
    checkbox1.checked = false;
}
```

Additional documentation can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.getcommandlineargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which will return a string array of your arguments, with the first element always being the application path.

```
string[] array = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
if (array.Length > 1 && array[1] == "/c")
    //Do something
```

You can also use the `args` array in your main method.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    if (array.Length > 0 && array[0] == "/c")
        //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (System.Environment.CommandLine.Contains("/c")){
    CheckBox1.Checked = False;
}
```